# How to implement the most cost effective shake detector

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have an app that needs to detect shake possibly whenever the user has their phone's screen on.  I've found plenty of examples of how to detect shake.  The example below being the most intriguing so far with use of Google code and adding in the gravity component.  My question is, can this code be improved?  Shake detection is pretty solid and i'm getting no false positives.  I'm mostly concerned with battery life improvement.

```
private static final int mMinimumForce   = 5;
private static final int mShakeFrequency = 500;
private static final int mMovesRequired  = 4;
private float[] mGravity                 = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
private float[] mAcceleration            = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
private static final int mXAxis          = 0;
private static final int mYAxis          = 1;
private static final int mZAxis          = 2;
private long mCurrentTime                = 0;
private long mLastTime                   = 0;
private int mMoveCount                   = 0;
private final float mAlpha               = 0.8f;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
        if(event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
            return;
        }


        // Set linear acceleration
        // Gravity components of x, y, and z acceleration
        mGravity[mXAxis] = mAlpha * mGravity[mXAxis] + (1 - mAlpha) * event.values[mXAxis];
        mGravity[mYAxis] = mAlpha * mGravity[mYAxis] + (1 - mAlpha) * event.values[mYAxis];
        mGravity[mZAxis] = mAlpha * mGravity[mZAxis] + (1 - mAlpha) * event.values[mZAxis];

        // Linear acceleration of x, y, z with gravity effect removed
        mAcceleration[mXAxis] = event.values[mXAxis] - mGravity[mXAxis];
        mAcceleration[mYAxis] = event.values[mYAxis] - mGravity[mYAxis];
        mAcceleration[mZAxis] = event.values[mZAxis] - mGravity[mZAxis];


        // Set maximum linear acceleration amongst x, y, z
        float maxAcceleration = mAcceleration[mXAxis];

        if (mAcceleration[mYAxis] > maxAcceleration)
        {
            maxAcceleration = mAcceleration[mYAxis];
        }

        if (mAcceleration[mZAxis] > maxAcceleration)
        {
            maxAcceleration = mAcceleration[mZAxis];
        }


        // Process shake
        if (maxAcceleration > mMinimumForce)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Shake detected");

            mCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (mLastTime == 0)
            {
                mLastTime = mCurrentTime;
            }

            long elapsedTime = mCurrentTime - mLastTime;

            if (elapsedTime > mShakeFrequency)
            {
                    mLastTime  = 0;
                    mMoveCount = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                mMoveCount++;

                if (mMoveCount > mMovesRequired)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Shake moves detected: " + mMovesRequired);
                    // do some work here

                        mLastTime  = 0;
                        mMoveCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your code is using the battery ? It relies on the OS's sensor events. So the sensors are using power independently of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lorenz.  To your point.  My code registered the listener right?  Other thoughts, my code opt'd to do floating point math.  Floating point math is a more expensive option regarding the CPU.  I can keep going...

Comment: You cannot listen to an event without registering it. Also it doesn't seem that you are doing to much calculations (no loop). So what's the point ? All other parts of your app will consume more. Think how much resources a screen refresh uses. You seem to try to economize 1 nano Ah, while the rest that's turning on the phone uses thousand time more...

Comment: Well obviously I called SensorManager.registerListener.  Maybe you can help clear up other people's posts talking about battery draining when they registerListener against the accelerometer?  Maybe you can also clear up this quote from d.android.com?  Always make sure to disable sensors you don't need, especially when your activity is paused. Failing to do so can drain the battery in just a few hours. Note that the system will not disable sensors automatically when the screen turns off.

Comment: Here's a little more information for you Lorenz.  As one example my phone's accelerometer uses .1mA of power when in use.  To your point about looping, the code is called on a frequency right?  Based on the rate at which you registered the listener.  Last and more important point I want to give to you Lorenz, my battery is draining "noticeably" faster leaving my listener registered.

Comment: It's still simple : you register the listener and it uses battery, you unregister and it stops using the battery. You cannot have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: In France we say : You can't have the butter, it's money and the smile of the dairy saleswoman.

Comment: Thank you for joining sides with me that sensors use battery.  Accelerometer uses battery and can drain a battery quickly.  I can't believe I had to work to prove that point, but I digress.  Moving on.  Yes I understand you can't have your cake and eat it too.  But we can try to be intelligent developers and do the absolute best we can right?  Floating point math in this looping sensor code is going to cause the CPU to work much more using more power.The lack of a filter only allowing the code to execute say every 1/200ms is going to cause it to run at the rate that we registered the listener.

Comment: I'm looking even beyond these basics for creative ideas.  I know a guy who wrote code against the GPS sensor, but he creatively turns it off and waits for the accelerometer to detect movement before reengaging it to save power.

Comment: Thanks for the French quote.  I know it all to well.  My brother lives in the Septième

Comment: @user1701153 , I want to implement the same feature in my app and also thinking about the same. Please share me your inputs on how did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google I/O docs have great information on all of your concerns.  Here's one such document.
https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/W_0300_CodingforLife-BatteryLifeThatIs.pdf

Your point on floating point math is correct.  While your code doesn't do much as far as calculations, the constant calling of it at high frequency could tax the CPU.

Your point on accelerometer using battery.  While each device is different regarding power consumption and this device doesn't use close to what the gyroscope does, it will show a marked difference if used non-stop on a full day of active screen use.

I agree that coding to the highest standards and efficiency is good regardless of if you see a marked difference in battery usage.  It's just being a good citizen.  If I can get 30 more minutes out of my phone, give it to me!!!

My suggestions on your code, which are really just reflective of Google's recommendations and many you're already speaking about.

- Register your listener with the lowest possible polling rate.
- Supplement point one with a filter at the beginning of the code to immediately return based on that poll rate not being satisfied.  (Current Time - Last Time) > POLL_RATE.  This is important because Android may not adhere to the poll rate registered in the listener.
- Favor integer math over floating point if you can.
- Investigate whether you can use AlarmManager and/or other sensors first that are more cost effective before engaging the accelerometer.  I don't know if this is possible in your case, but worth checking into.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Appreciate the help.  I'm not sure if AlarmManager will work, but thanks for giving options to consider.